# Absolute element on table cell

Tags: css

I am trying to get text view all with arrow show on `hover` like shown on picture. 
The problem is that I can't position (view all) like an absolute element in table-cell (which is `li`).

http://jsfiddle.net/v3daa/

[image]

Comment: Why dont you create another image for that and on hover display that.??

Comment: The problem is that I cant position text or image on top of li (absolute) because li is table cell

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `li` element have `position:relative`, and then create a new `div` within each `li` and give those `position:absolute`:

```
li {
    position: relative;
 }

 .newDiv{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
 }
```